# How to find differences in CSV files?

Tags: macos, csv, terminal

I have two csv files which, if open with TextEdit, are exactly the same. However, when run through Terminal with  'diff' command, it shows some differences that I was not able to determine.

```
MacBook-Pro-2 Desktop % diff goodcsv.csv completecsv.csv
1c1
< ﻿AccountNo.,PromptPay ID,Account Name,Amount,Description
---
> AccountNo.,PromptPay ID,Account Name,Amount,Description
```

Comment: End of line character differs?

Comment: How about diffing them with a Python framework? Something like this: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-compare-two-text-files-in-python/

Comment: @Jarek, the difference is in the first character of line 1 (`1c1`), that's not about the end of the line. See my write-up/answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm pretty sure it's a [BOM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark) at the beginning of one of the files.

Diff is telling you the difference is the 1st line, 1st char: `1c1`.

I copied your header and made up a first row:

```
AccountNo.,PromptPay ID,Account Name,Amount,Description
1,2,Acme,2000.00,For a foo
```

I then added a BOM to that and saved it as another file:

```sh
% gocsv clean --add-bom input.csv > input_bom.csv
```

and now when I diff the two, I get your result:

```sh
% diff input.csv input_bom.csv
1c1
< AccountNo.,PromptPay ID,Account Name,Amount,Description
---
> AccountNo.,PromptPay ID,Account Name,Amount,Description
```

For BSD (macOS Terminal), you can visualize a BOM with `less` or `hexdump`.  I find the output from `less` to me more straightforward:

```sh
% less input_bom.csv
<U+FEFF>AccountNo.,PromptPay ID,Account Name,Amount,Description
1,2,Acme,2000.00,For a foo
```

`FEFF` is the Unicode code point for the BYTE ORDER MARK character.

`hexdump` will give you the complete and unvarnished truth for what's in your file:

```sh
% hexdump -C input_bom.csv
00000000  ef bb bf 41 63 63 6f 75  6e 74 4e 6f 2e 2c 50 72  |...AccountNo.,Pr|
00000010  6f 6d 70 74 50 61 79 20  49 44 2c 41 63 63 6f 75  |omptPay ID,Accou|
00000020  6e 74 20 4e 61 6d 65 2c  41 6d 6f 75 6e 74 2c 44  |nt Name,Amount,D|
00000030  65 73 63 72 69 70 74 69  6f 6e 0a 31 2c 32 2c 41  |escription.1,2,A|
00000040  63 6d 65 2c 32 30 30 30  2e 30 30 2c 46 6f 72 20  |cme,2000.00,For |
00000050  61 20 66 6f 6f 0a                                 |a foo.|
00000056
```

The first three bytes, `ef bb bf`, is the UTF-8 encoded byte sequence that makes up the BOM; you can also see something is there, but cannot be printed, from the three leading dots, `...AccountNo`.

I used GoCSV's [clean](https://github.com/aotimme/gocsv#clean) command to add the BOM; you can use its `--strip-bom` option to get rid of it.  If you're doing anything with CSVs on the command line, GoCSV is a fantastic tool; it's [prebuilt for macOS Intel and ARM](https://github.com/aotimme/gocsv/releases).