# Difference between two csv files

Tags: csv, export-to-csv

I have a problem determining the difference between two csv files.
I have compared them line by line and they are completely the same (as text).
When I use terminal diff to see the difference, it tells me that every line is different.
After checking the size of each file, I realize the difference of number of byte between two files are the same as the number of lines in each file. I suspect that I miss one byte for each line. However, as I mentioned, I cannot see any difference if I open them as text files. Is there any tool I can use to compare them and know whats the difference?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to find differences in CSV files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71371669/how-to-find-differences-in-csv-files) That diff in that question was almost certainly about a BOM. Your diffs seem to be caused by line endings, something like \r\n vs \n (the one extra byte per line), but the tools and methods I recommend will still help you. Especially GoCSV, its nature is to normalize all line endings to \n.

Answer (score 0):

with this one, there can be a spacing difference or some Unicode character in one of the files and that might be causing the issue for you.

I had a python script that gave me the difference between the two files, hopefully, this will help you.

```
import csv


def main():
    old_file = 'oldfile.txt'
    new_file = 'newfile.txt'

    # Create sets to store the unique values from each file
    old_set = set()
    new_set = set()

    # Open the old file and add the first column of each row to the old_set
    with open(old_file, 'r') as f:
        reader = csv.reader(f)
        for row in reader:
            old_set.add(row)

    # Open the new file and add the first column of each row to the new_set
    with open(new_file, 'r') as f:
        reader = csv.reader(f)
        for row in reader:
            new_set.add(row)

    
    # Print the missing values
    print(missing_values)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

PS. if you don't see anything printed, try reversing the file names, it can be one way or the other.
hopefully, this helps